# remove webstageview flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, actionscript

Hello I'm build a mobile flex app and I am using a WebStageView but when I go to a new view the web stage stay on top of it. How can i remove it?

This is my code:

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 150, this.stage.stageWidth, this .stage.stageHeight-500); 
            webView.stage = this.stage; 
            var htmlString:String = data["encoded"];
            webView.loadString( htmlString );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

webView.stage = null;